# Passing an ADO SQL connection ByVal

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have an existing application written in Visual Basic. It's a web application build on ASP.NET and WCF that we use for reporting.

The result is a page that refreshes it's data every set amount of time. Usually after a day or so, this particular page crashes and the service must be reset, however other pages work. My working theory has to do with connections.

Connections to SQL Server are made through the class `SQLDataAccess`. This class creates a new connection when it is instantiated, the connection can be closed by calling a method on the class.

Most calls look like this:

```
Try
    existingConnection.DataRequest.CommandText = "dbo.p_Select_Table"
    DataAccessConnection.ExecuteDataSet()
Catch
Finally
    If(existingConnection IsNot Nothign) Then
        existingConnection.closeConnection()
    End If
End Try
```

However two connections are initially made, then both connections are passed around more than this bug report was. They get passed `ByVal`.

Will this create new connections and neglect to close the old one?

Comment: There is no need to save/re use connections; try creating a new one each time and see if that helps.  See: [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know about creating a new one each time. That's what I do in my code. When I need a connection, I create one, then use it, then close it. However I'm more concerned if the passed connections are persisting because of the way they are passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass any reference type by value, what you are passing is a reference.  No object is copied.  Passing a method parameter by value is basically just the same as assigning one variable to another.  If the type is a value type then the object is copied and both variables contain different objects.  For reference types, both variables refer to the same object.  It's just like objects in the real world.  If I lend you my car, does that mean there are two cars?  No it doesn't, and it's the same when you pass a reference type object by value.